# Minecraft Launcher won't run latest version of Minecraft (v1.7.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I recently updated my Minecraft Launcher, and v1.7.2 of the game appeared in the drop-down menu of which version to play. The version I played before updating the launcher was v1.6.2 without any issues.

So I installed the new version in the launcher and then tried to run it. When I press play the "wait" icon appears on my cursor for a second then goes and nothing happens. I left it for about 10 minutes before retrying.

I then pressed the force clean button and it updated the game files automatically. When I tried to run the game the same thing happened. I went back and selected v1.6.2 and the launcher ran it straight away.

I can't figure out why v1.7.2 of the game won't launch?

Comment: Look for a small green bar above the play bar.. This is a validation/download bar to snag the new version. It could just be that its taking a while to download the new version... though 10min does seem a bit long assuming you have a decent internet connection.

Comment: What launcher are you using? The official launcher doesn't have a "force clean" button, and can't be updated manually like you're describing.

Comment: (Also, next time don't delete your question and repost it. Use the **edit** button instead if you need to make changes to it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you're using a different launcher than normal. Normal MC launchers don't have a "Force Clean" button. Try downloading the original launcher from here- https://minecraft.net/download

Click on the blue link that says "Minecraft.exe". Start it up and login, then in the bottom left it should say "Ready to download & install Minecraft 1.7.2".